# How do I handle persistent currency switching throughout my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I support 3 currencies in my app `GBP, JMD, USD`.

When a user selects a currency on one page, it reloads the page and sets the `session[:currency]` variable accordingly. The challenge is, depending on the currency they select of the 3, the behavior isn't always predictable and the same.

I may have just been looking at this logic too long, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work and would love an extra pair of eyes.

So I started with this in my `application_controller.rb`:

```
unless params[:currency].blank?
  if params[:currency] != session[:currency] || session[:previous_currency].blank?
    session[:previous_currency] = session[:currency]
    session[:currency] = params[:currency] 
  end
else
  if session[:currency].blank?
    session[:currency] = 'JMD'
  end
end
```

That didn't really capture `USD, GBP`.

So that has since been modified to this:

```
unless params[:currency].blank? && session[:currency].blank?
  if (params[:currency].eql? "JMD") || (session[:currency].eql? "JMD")
    session[:currency] = 'JMD'
    session[:locale] = :en
    session[:previous_currency] = 'GBP'
  elsif (params[:currency].eql? "GBP") || (session[:currency].eql? "GBP")
    session[:locale] = :"en-GB"
  elsif (params[:currency].eql? "USD") || (session[:currency].eql? "USD")
    session[:locale] = :en
  elsif params[:currency] != session[:currency] || session[:previous_currency].blank?
    session[:previous_currency] = session[:currency]
    session[:currency] = params[:currency]
  end
else
  session[:currency] = 'JMD'
  session[:locale] = :en
end
```

The issue is this one doesn't work when I am going from any currency to `GBP`, and I can't quite figure out why.

What I mean is, say I change from `USD` to `GBP`. If I go to another page (say the homepage) it reverts to the default `JMD` currency. When I want it to stay `GBP` just like it does if I switch to `USD` and change pages everything stays in `USD`.

What am I missing?

Comment: It would be easier, if you create a mapping hash for the currencies, and then merge with the session `session.merge!(mapping[params[:currency])`

Comment: Interesting solution @Archer. Would you mind fleshing that out as a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a mapping it would be much easier as with lots of `elsif`.
I hope it's logical correct. It's not easy to understand your problem clearly, but maybe it helps.

```rb
if params[:currency] != session[:currency] || session[:previous_currency].blank?
  return session.merge!(previous_currency: session[:currency], params[:currency]) 
end

default = { currency: 'JMD', locale: :en }
mapping = { 'JMD': { currency: 'JMD', locale: :en, previous_currency: 'GBP' },
            'GBP': { locale: :"en-GB" },
            'USD': { locale: :en } }

# if you're using Ruby >= 2.3.0
values = mapping.detect{ |k, v| k.to_s == params[:currency] || session[:currency] }&.last

# if you're using Ruby < 2.3.0
values = mapping.detect{ |k, v| k.to_s == params[:currency] || session[:currency] }.try(&:last)

session.merge!(values || default)
```